# Vertica SQL Function used to split string into separate columns

Tags: sql, split, vertica

Is there a way in SQL to split a string into n columns based on a delimiter in a the string.  I'm aware of the SPLIT_PART function where there are three arguments, the string, the delimiter, and the nth delimiter in the string.  Example:

```
select 
  split_part('2016-01-01 00:11:00|Sprout|0', '|', 1),  split_part('2016-01-01 00:11:00|Sprout|0', '|', 2), split_part('2016-01-01 00:11:00|Sprout|0', '|', 3);
```

Is there a way to do this without the third argument where you would just supply the string and the delimiter and you would end up with however many columns the delimiter appears in your string?

Once Vertica allows Python based UDFs, I know this is an easy fix using the .split() method, but is there a solution currently?  I know this is likely a long shot, but I'm mostly asking out of curiosity as using split_part works perfectly for my purposes.

This not being possible would be an acceptable answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok. If you're happy to just get the n-th token of the string, try:

```
    SQL>SELECT
    ...>  regexp_substr(
    ...>    '2016-01-01 00:11:00|Sprout|0' -- source string
    ...>  , '[|]?([^|]+)' -- pattern (an optional bar, followed by many non-bars, which we remember as the 1st group)
    ...>  , 1             -- starting from begin of string: position 1
    ...>  , 1             -- the N-th occurrence
    ...>  , ''            -- no regexp modifier
    ...>  , 1             -- we want the only remembered group - the 1st
    ...>  ) the_first
    ...>, regexp_substr(
    ...>    '2016-01-01 00:11:00|Sprout|0' -- source string
    ...>  , '[|]?([^|]+)' -- pattern (an optional bar, followed by many non-bars, which we remember as the 1st group)
    ...>  , 1             -- starting from begin of string: position 1
    ...>  , 2             -- the N-th occurrence
    ...>  , ''            -- no regexp modifier
    ...>  , 1             -- we want the only remembered group - the 1st
    ...>  ) the_second
    ...>, regexp_substr(
    ...>    '2016-01-01 00:11:00|Sprout|0' -- source string
    ...>  , '[|]?([^|]+)' -- pattern (an optional bar, followed by many non-bars, which we remember as the 1st group)
    ...>  , 1             -- starting from begin of string: position 1
    ...>  , 3             -- the N-th occurrence
    ...>  , ''            -- no regexp modifier
    ...>  , 1             -- we want the only remembered group - the 1st
    ...>  ) the_third
    ...>;
    the_first                   |the_second                  |the_third
    2016-01-01 00:11:00         |Sprout                      |0
```

But if you want to pivot your delimited string, so that each token forms a new line - two possibilities:

```
    SQL>-- manual, using regexp_substr ...
    ...>with
    ...>the_array as (
    ...>          select  1 as idx
    ...>union all select  2
    ...>union all select  3
    ...>union all select  4
    ...>union all select  5
    ...>union all select  6
    ...>union all select  7
    ...>union all select  8
    ...>union all select  9
    ...>union all select 10 -- increase if you might get a bigger array than one of 10 elements
    ...>)
    ...> ,concepts as (
    ...>select '2016-01-01 00:11:00|Sprout|0' as concepts_list
    ...>)
    ...>select * from (
    ...>  select
    ...>   idx
    ...>  ,trim(
    ...>    regexp_substr(
    ...>     concepts_list -- source string
    ...>    ,'[|]?([^|]+)' -- pattern (an optional bar, followed by many non-bars, which we remember as the 1st group)
    ...>    ,1             -- starting from begin of string: position 1
    ...>    ,idx           -- the idx-th occurrence
    ...>    ,''            -- no regexp modifier
    ...>    ,1             -- we want the only remembered group - the 1st
    ...>    )
    ...>   ) as concept
    ...>  from concepts
    ...>  cross join the_array
    ...>) foo
    ...>where concept <> ''
    ...>;
    idx                 |concept
                       1|2016-01-01 00:11:00
                       3|0
                       2|Sprout
    select succeeded; 3 rows fetched
    SQL>-- using the strings_package on:
    ...>-- https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages/blob/master/strings_package/src/StringTokenizerDelim.cpp
    ...>WITH csvtab(id,delimstring) AS (
    ...>          SELECT 1,'2016-01-01 00:11:00|Sprout|0'
    ...>UNION ALL SELECT 2,'2016-01-02 00:11:00|Trout|1'
    ...>UNION ALL SELECT 3,'2016-01-03 00:11:00|Salmon|2'
    ...>UNION ALL SELECT 4,'2016-01-04 00:11:00|Bass|3'
    ...>)
    ...>SELECT id, words
    ...>FROM (
    ...>  SELECT id, v_txtindex.StringTokenizerDelim(delimstring,'|') OVER (PARTITION by id) FROM csvtab
    ...>) a
    ...>ORDER BY 1;
    id                  |words
                       1|2016-01-01 00:11:00
                       1|Sprout
                       1|0
                       2|2016-01-02 00:11:00
                       2|Trout
                       2|1
                       3|2016-01-03 00:11:00
                       3|Salmon
                       3|2
                       4|2016-01-04 00:11:00
                       4|Bass
                       4|3
    select succeeded; 12 rows fetched
```

Comment: I was more wondering if I could get separate columns without having 3 items in the select statement.  If you're familiar with Python, I'd want the effect of string.split('|').  Totally fine if this isn't possible in SQL.  Your first example is a route I'm probably going to go by using the vertica function SPLIT_PART(string, delimiter, occurence).